# Warbling circle using d3

Tags: d3.js, css-selectors

I wanted to draw a pulsating <s>warbling</s> circle on a geomap using d3, using [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/chiester/11267307) for guidance. However—and I know this is a very basic question, so apologies—I can't seem to get the selector to fire right. Here is the relevant code:

```
    layer2
            .attr("id", "locations")
            .selectAll(".state")
            .data(columbia.features)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "location")
            .attr("r", "4px")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return proj(d['geometry']['coordinates'])[0]; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return proj(d['geometry']['coordinates'])[1]; })
            .attr("d", path)
            .each(pulse);

    function pulse() {
        var circle = svg.select(".location");
        console.log(circle);
        (function repeat() {
            circle = circle.transition()
                    .duration(2000)
                    .attr("stroke-width", 20)
                    .attr("r", 10)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(2000)
                    .attr('stroke-width', 0.5)
                    .attr("r", 200)
                    .ease('sine')
                    .each("end", repeat);
        })();
    }
```

Right now I have:

```
var circle = svg.select(".location");
```

What should I have instead of `.location`?

[Here is the full file](https://github.com/ResidentMario/nyc-buildings/blob/master/final-visualization.html).

**Edit**: got it; I need `selectAll`, not`select`.

Comment: Also if anyone can point me to a good reference on d3 selectors, much obliged!

Comment: you want a circle that makes the sound of a bird singing? Or did you mean wobbling?

Comment: Sorry, just my own peculiar slang I guess...